# Entity Mapping in Rasa

Tags: rasa-nlu, rasa-core, rasa

I’m currently trying to build a multi-lingual chatbot. I’m trying to re-create the method used in this [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7u28QgFGDp8&feature=youtu.be&t=468) . My question is how to create and then use the entity mapping file. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

The video seems to refer to entity synonyms [here](https://youtu.be/7u28QgFGDp8?t=628). This is documentated on the rasa documentation [here](https://rasa.com/docs/rasa/nlu/training-data-format/#entity-synonyms).